# Gradle: Can I compile code that depends on its own output?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, gradle

This is a strange question, but it's not theoretical...

1. I'd like to make a Gradle project that uses a `buildSrc` with a java project inside. That java project defines some classes used in the build process.
2. The nasty trick is, the Gradle project produces a bunch of outputs, including  **modified** classes that belong to the Java project of the `buildSrc` itself.

Is there any way to express this with Gradle?

The only solution I have in mind right now is: run the whole build script twice in a row. Is there any way to avoid that? For example, by generating the modified code for `buildSrc`, re-compiling the `buildSrc` and then generating the additional outputs of the main Gradle project?

Comment: Can't you get rid of the cyclic dependency? Separate the Groovy project into the code generating module, and the parts that consume the output of the code generator. (And/or potentially some shared code.) Then run the code generator, compile the generated Java, compile your main thing.

Comment: My first instinct, too. Unfortunately I'm working against a legacy project where the code-generation actually uses the classes that it outputs. (The process was bootstrapped by hand a while back.)

Comment: Okay but the cyclic dependency pretty much implies you can't not do this in one step. (Technically, not even two is correct, the Right way would be to re-run the code generator until nothing changes.)

Comment: I agree it's multiple *steps* (tasks). I just want to see if I can do it with a single invocation of Gradle.

Comment: Then uh... split out the codegen into its own module, and invoke codegen using a [custom task](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html)? It's still kind of fragile but at least it's automated when building the main module.

Comment: But where to keep the Java source the codegen uses? Would like to have it in just one place, not two. And I don't know how to re-compile `buildSrc` in the middle of an execution.

Comment: I've tried to address this last question (how to re-compile buildSrc) in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, building on Michael Easter's awesome example, I can have the main-level build call a `GradleBuild` on one of its own tasks:

```
task generateNewCode() << {
  println("tracer top build")

  // BuildTool is a Java class defined in `buildSrc`
  // ... and it has a cyclic dependency on its own 
  // output (eek -- but that's what I'm dealing with!)
  BuildTool.generateNewCode();
}

task generateDocs(type: GradleBuild) {
  buildFile='build.gradle'
  tasks = ['generateDocs_Real']
}

task generateDocs_Real << {
  BuildTool.outputDocumentation();
}

generateDocs.dependsOn generateNewCode
```

Then I can invoke `gradle generateDocs` to do:

1. Codegen (creating new java classes in `buildSrc`
2. Recompile `buildSrc`
3. Generate documentation using helpers from the recompiled `buidSrc`

Answer (score 1):

I believe that section 59.4 of [the Gradle doc](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html) can help you.

Using Gradle 1.8, I tried to "run another Gradle build from a build", where the other Gradle build is buildSrc.

This does not involve codegen, but might be enough to help.

To replicate, I have a simple Java project in buildSrc, with a build.gradle that looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

build << { 
    println "TRACER: hello from buildSrc java build"
}

task compile2() << {
    println "TRACER: hello from buildSrc compile2"
}
```

The 'build' task is called automatically via the buildSrc mechanism. The goal is to call 'compile2' from the root. At the root, the build.gradle looks like this:

```
task build1() << {
    println "TRACER: top-level build1" 
}

task build2(type: GradleBuild) {
    buildFile = 'buildSrc/build.gradle'
    tasks = ['compile2']
}

build2.dependsOn build1
```

At the root level, the output is as follows:

```
$ gradle build2

:buildSrc:compileJava etc etc
TRACER: hello from buildSrc java build
TRACER: top-level build1
TRACER: hello from buildSrc compile2
```

This shows that:

- the Java project in buildSrc is compiled
- the root 'build1' is called (compile your main project here)
- the buildSrc 'compile2' is called

The classpath and codegen is nasty but may be straight-forward.

Comment: This is super-helpful in its own right, and I really appreciate the concrete example. But if I understand correctly, after the main build script calls `compile2` of `buildSrc`, the main build script won't have the newly-compiled `buildSrc` classes available to execute. (That is, there's no way to swap in the new classes from the new `buildSrc`). Is that right?